# sql server subquery join error

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I want to update GroupID column of massemail_emailmaster and set it to the value as it is stored on massemail_groupmaster. Both table has GroupName column which is I have used to join in the subquery.
But the following query is giving me error. Error message is incorrect syntax near a3. I don't understand the mistake in syntax here. Please help.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[massmail_emailmaster]  a3
set a3.GroupId =
      (select TOP 1 a1.GroupID from [dbo].[massmail_groupmaster] a1 
         join [dbo].[massmail_emailmaster] a2
      on a1.[groupname] = a2.[groupname]
where a3.[GroupName]=a2.[GroupName])
```

DDL of table `[dbo]. [massmail_emailmaster]`

```
(ClientID, varchar(50)),
           (uid, int)
           (Name, varchar(100))
           (GroupName, varchar(100))
           (Email, varchar(100))
           GroupId, int)
```

DDL of table

```
[dbo]. [massmail_groupmaster]
 (Clientid, varchar(50))
           ,(uid, int)
           ,(groupname, varchar(100))
(GroupId,int))
```

Comment: Can you provide DDLs, or better yet, and SQLFiddle for your tables?

Comment: Shouldnt the join come before the set syntax?

Comment: @Mureinik I added column details of both tables.

Comment: @KayNelson Can you please elaborate your suggestion? I am really confused on this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the alias in the `update` when you later define it in the `from` clause.  (This is a "perverse" situation where the alias is defined *after* its first use.)

```
UPDATE a3
    set GroupId = (select TOP 1 a1.GroupID
                   from [dbo].[massmail_groupmaster] a1
                   where a1.[groupname] = a3.[groupname]
                  )
    FROM [dbo].[massmail_emailmaster] a3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  a2
SET a2.GroupId = (SELECT TOP 1 a.GroupID 
                   FROM [dbo].[massmail_groupmaster] a 
                   INNER JOIN [dbo].[massmail_emailmaster] b
                   ON a.[groupname] = b.[groupname]
                  ) 
FROM  [dbo].[massmail_emailmaster] a2
WHERE a.[groupname] = a2.[groupname]
```

Comment: This change removed the error. Just one more change in the inner subquery to make it perfectly working. I added where statement "where a.[groupname]=a1.[groupname]" in the subquery at the end. Otherwise it would set all groupID to same value. Thanks a lot man! Your suggestion really helped.